# Value inside inputbox is not changing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, input, tailwind-css

What I wanna do: if input box detects the keyword 'team:' it should display a svg instead.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isSidebar: false,
  }
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''}
  }  
change = () => {
    this.setState({ value: this.state.value.replace("team:", <TeamSearchIcon />) })
  }
```

this is my app component

```
<input class="w-full rounded p-2 pl-5 pr-5 focus:outline-none text-lg" type="text" placeholder="search..." value={this.state.value} onChange={this.change}>
</input>
```

this is my input box
 is a svg imported as a component

If I do this.setState({value: 'hi'}) it works but replacing doesn't work

Edit: please also tell how to replace several keywords ?

any comments are appreciated!

Comment: To clarify, you have an `<input type="text"/>` textbox and you're trying to display an SVG inside that? Unfortunately textboxes like that can only contain text, not images. Would you be satisfied with replacing the entire textbox with an SVG?

Comment: @HanSeoul-Oh what are alternative to this ? I dont want to replace whole textbox with a SVG. StackOverflow has this input box too . When u r going to post qs u have to select tags. i want an input box like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick StackOverflow does is that it *looks* like there are tags inside the textbox, but actually the only textbox is the part you can type in, and instead a box containing both the tags and the actual textbox is styled to look like a textbox.

This is a tutorial to build such a thing yourself: https://jerrylowm.medium.com/build-a-tags-input-react-component-from-scratch-1524f02acb9a

There are also React libraries that already do this: https://betterstack.dev/projects/react-tag-input/

Comment: Thanks a lot, one more question - In that React lib u sent, can I change enter into ':' so if someone adds a colon it makes a tag and can I restrict to what length can it choose like  if I press team: then it should make a tag with 4 letters behind ':' ?

Comment: @HarshitGupta Its documentation doesn't permit that, but if you follow the tutorial to build one yourself, you can make it do whatever you want :)

Answer (score 0):

Using "replace", you are effectively trying to treat the JSX component TeamSearchIcon as part of a string variable. But, it's not a string variable.

One solution is to take your string variable, and split it up into an array of strings, like const stringArray = this.state.value.split('team:');

Then use "map" function and display the appropriate components -- either something to print the string value, or TeamSearchIcon.

Comment: but if I do this.setState({value: this.state.value}) it shows a blank input box where it should show the same value